# android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED is triggered more than once on GPS/Location being manually switched on device

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-gps

I have gone trough several resources which deal with this problem, but none with a satisfactory explanation or solution. Some of the content I have gone through are:

[Broadcast receiver called 2 times when turning off GPS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31789424/broadcast-receiver-called-2-times-when-turning-off-gps)

[My BroadcastReceiver is called two times when turning on/off wifi or gps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47872186/my-broadcastreceiver-is-called-two-times-when-turning-on-off-wifi-or-gps)

[android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED BroadcastReceiver fires off many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28931366/android-location-providers-changed-broadcastreceiver-fires-off-many-times)

[How to catch GPS off broadcast once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31123253/how-to-catch-gps-off-broadcast-once/31583305)

I therefore, am re-posting this question.

The problem statement is simple, I have a broadcast receiver that gets triggered whenever there is a change in the GPS/Location status of the device. The problem is that the onReceive() method gets called more than once (4 times to be precise).

**I have registered my receiver in my manifest file (and nowhere else):**

```
        <receiver android:name=".broadcasts.DeviceGpsStatusReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

I have also ensured that this receiver isn't registered anywhere else within my application.

The broadcast receiver is designed as follows:

```
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().matches("android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED")) {
            // my content
        }
    }
```

Even with this change, I see the onReceive() overridden method being triggered multiple times. Why is this the case? Is there a way to resolve this?